# Cascading react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display the cascading drop downs. That is data in subcategory would be displayed based on the category selection.
Trying to handle the scenario where the category does not have the subcategory that is it is null. I want to hide the subcategory.

Data :

```
  const categoryData = [
    {
      categoryName: 'Sandwitches',
      subCategory: ['Veg', 'Non veg']
    },
    {
      categoryName: 'Beverages',
      subCategory: ['Hot', 'Cold', 'Smoothie']
    },
    {
      categoryName: 'Pasta',
      subCategory: null
    },

    {
      categoryName: 'Cakes',
      subCategory: ['Mousse Cake', 'Naked Cake', 'Wedding Cake']
    },
    {
      categoryName: 'Gelato',
      subCategory: ['Hot', 'Cold', 'Smoothie']
    }
  ];
```

```
<InputTextContainer>
          <InputLabel>Category</InputLabel>
          <InputSelect
            value={category}
            name="category"
            onChange={onChange('category')}
          >
            {categoryData.map((category, index) => {
              return <InputOption>{category.categoryName}</InputOption>;
            })}
          </InputSelect>
        </InputTextContainer>
        {
          <InputTextContainer>
            <InputLabel>Sub Category</InputLabel>
            <InputSelect
              value={subCategory}
              name="subCategory"
              onChange={onChange('subCategory')}
            >
              {categoryData
                .filter(selectedCategory => {
                  return selectedCategory.categoryName === category;
                })
                .map((category, index) =>
                  category.subCategory.map(subcategory => {
                    {
                      return <InputOption>{subcategory}</InputOption>;
                    }
                  })
                )}
            </InputSelect>
          </InputTextContainer>
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of your return statement, you can declare a variable `selectedCategory`

```
const selectedCategory = categoryData.filter((c) => {
  return c.categoryName === category;
});
```

Then you can conditionally render the component

```
{
  selectedCategory.length > 0 && selectedCategory[0].subCategory && (
    <InputTextContainer>
      <InputLabel>Sub Category</InputLabel>
      <InputSelect
        value={subCategory}
        name="subCategory"
        onChange={onChange("subCategory")}
      >
        {selectedCategory.map((category, index) =>
          category.subCategory.map((subcategory) => {
            {
              return <InputOption>{subcategory}</InputOption>;
            }
          })
        )}
      </InputSelect>
    </InputTextContainer>
  );
}
```

Also if you're sure that category names are unique `find` might be a better choice than `filter` here

> The [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Comment: Works great! "0" is rendering on the screen think that is from the selectedCategory.length..

Comment: Can you help me putting it in a state so that whenever category changes the logic is implemented

Comment: I've updated the answer to handle that case. What do you mean by putting in the state? It should be updated when category is changed.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. Goal is to hide the InputConatanier entirely if the subcategory is null or empty..

Comment: You mean, you don't want to show the category selector either?

Comment: For Pasta there should be Subcategory field as it does not have sub categories.

Comment: For beverages it should be rendered

Comment: For beverages it should be rendered

Comment: Did you try out the answer? Isn't it working like that only?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the direction.. selectedCategory[0].subCategory.length > 0  was needed to handle the scenario..

Comment: No issues :) Though your onChange handler doesn't look correct right now. You're supposed to pass function's reference which can be called at a later point. But you're calling it right away with 'category' argument.